# Let's go hike/hiking at the park

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct and why?

`Let's go hiking at the park.`

or

`Let's go hike at the park`.

On the second example (*hike*), should that actually be `let's go to hike at the park`?

Also works for things like: skate/skating, bike/biking...

(I'm not sure if this is a duplicate because I'm not exactly sure what I should be searching for...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves the catenation of verbs (once you've sorted out the preposition if necessary).

> We go / are going / went hiking

is a standard, accepted construction; come / go + -ing form. Quite a few other verbs catenate with the -ing form also.

And placing this after "Let's" poses no problems:

> Let's go shopping / dancing / fishing / hiking.

But the other construction is not so easy to evaluate, being of the form verb + bare infinitive.

[Here](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/129959500/AL-MUSTANSIRIYA-UNIVERSITY) is found:

> **Catenative Verbs Followed by Bare Infinitive**
>
> Christophorsen and Sandred (1970:149) hold that there are few CVs
>   followed by this type
>   of complement.  Among these CVs are: (1) help, (2) some verbs that may
>   be combined with the BI of another verb in certain set phrases such as
>   hear say, make believe, make do, (3) a number of combinations with the
>   verb let such as let go [= release], let fly, let drop, etc., (4) some petrified
>   phrases followed by BI such as had rather, had sooner, had better,
>   etc.  Consider the following examples:
>   2.77  I helped tidy up the room.
>   2.78  He let fly a string of abuse.
>   2.79  I heard say that he is back.
>   2.80  You had better go now. ...
>
> In this pattern, only the verb help, and the petrified phrases can
>   combine freely with the other verbs.  Combinations such as let fly,
>   make do, hear tell, hear say are virtually a closed set.  They are
>   fixed phrases or idioms (Palmer, 1974:160); (Chalker, 1984:149).

However, the [bare infinitive *is* used](http://ifa.amu.edu.pl/sap/files/41/02Anderson.pdf), [p 48] especially in the US, in catenations with the verb go (but only in the infinitive):

> Go fly a kite!
>
> Go take a hike! (BrE would usually have 'Go and take a hike!')
>
> Let's go take a ride.
>
> Let's go hike the Palos Trail System.
>
> Let's go hike in the Appalachians.

*He went take a ride.

Answer (score 3):

A native speaker would say neither, because in this context the preposition needed is not *at* but *in*. Your sentence would normally occur as *Let’s go for a hike in the park*. However, in the UK at least, parks, unless you mean national parks, are not places where you go for a hike. In a city park, you go for a walk.

Comment: Agreed Barrie.  The same is true in the US.  Although a national park is not required for a hike, typically the verb hiking is used to describe the act of walking on a "hiking trail" (usually in hilly or mountainous terrain.)

Comment: It depends on the park— even in those in the middle of big cities. Visiting [Rock Creek Park](http://www.nps.gov/rocr/planyourvisit/things2do.htm), [Griffith Park](http://www.laparks.org/dos/parks/griffithpk/hiking.htm), or [Balboa Park](http://www.balboapark.org/in-the-park/hiking-and-biking-trails) may not exactly be a trek on the Muir Trail, but would certainly be more of a hike than a stroll or a jog.

Comment: It sounds like we are all in agreement that [hiking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiking) carries a certain connotation that is not implicit in all forms of walking.